# Copying a webpage content to the Clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to copy a certain area from a webpage and copy it to the clipboard, selected area may be of anything like image,chart,text etc.?

Comment: ctr+c ->  ctr+v or use ctr+s and some text mainpulation

Answer (score 0):

You can try

**to select** `document.getElementById ("ID_OF_THE_ELEMENT_YOU_WANT_TO_SELECT")`

**To Copy** `document.execCommand ("Copy")`